# If Image not edited then bring same image in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$edit_id=$product_id;
    if(isset($_GET['edit_id']) && !empty($_GET['edit_id']))
    {
      $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
      $stmt_edit = $conn->prepare('SELECT Product_name, Product_type,       Product_price, Product_desc, Product_quantity, product_weight, Product_image FROM products WHERE Product_id =:uid');
      $stmt_edit->execute(array(':uid'=>$id));
      $edit_row = $stmt_edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      extract($edit_row);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['edit_product'])){
        $edit_id=$product_id;
        $product_name = $_POST['product_Name'];
        $product_type = $_POST['product_Type'];
        $product_price = $_POST['product_Price'];
        $product_desc = $_POST['product_Desc'];
        $product_quantity = $_POST['product_Quantity'];
        $product_weight = $_POST['product_Weight'];
        $product_image = $_FILES['product_Image']['name'];
        $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_Image']['tmp_name'];
        $result =mysql_query("SELECT Product_image FROM products WHERE Product_id = '$edit_id'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            $userpic = $edit_row['Product_image'];

        }
        else
        {
         move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");
        } 
        $edit_product=" update products set Product_name='$product_name',Product_type='$product_type',Product_price='$product_price',Product_desc='$product_desc',Product_quantity='$product_quantity',Product_weight='$product_weight',Product_image='$product_image' where Product_id = '$edit_id' ";

        $edit_pro = mysqli_query($conn, $edit_product);
        if($edit_pro){
            echo "<script>alert('Product has been edited to table')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view_product','_self')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

An image is edited but when other things excluding image are edited then an image will be deleted from a database. So I need the solution for this. thank you in advance

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Man, verify if file uploaded before update on database ou move upload, and check if file is allowed types like image

you can do this:

```
if ($_FILES['product_Image']['error'] == 0) { // no problems on upload

  $allowed_types = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png");
  $product_image = $_FILES['product_Image']['name'];
  $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_Image']['tmp_name'];
  $product_image_type = $_FILES['product_Image']['type'];

  if (in_array($product_image_type, $allowed_types)) {
    move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");
  }
} else {
   // not change image on database, only others fields
}
```